Sometimes Ubuntu 22.04 LTS freezes when suspended
Sometimes when I suspend my laptop, it goes into an unresponsive state.
The following is the log of the journalctl that I think is related to the problem:
 NetworkManager[988]: <info>  [1725701470.9629] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
 NetworkManager[988]: <info>  [1725701470.9629] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
 wpa_supplicant[990]: wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
 wpa_supplicant[990]: wlp2s0: Failed to initiate AP scan
 kernel: Freezing user space processes
 kernel: Freezing user space processes failed after 20.006 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
 kernel: task:gvfsd-recent    state:D stack:0     pid:5074  tgid:5074  ppid:3714   flags:0x00004006
 kernel: Call Trace:
 kernel:  <TASK>
 kernel:  __schedule+0x27c/0x6a0
 kernel:  schedule+0x33/0x110
 kernel:  request_wait_answer+0xda/0x2a0
 kernel:  ? __pfx_autoremove_wake_function+0x10/0x10
 kernel:  fuse_simple_request+0x19d/0x2f0
 kernel:  fuse_dentry_revalidate+0x153/0x3a0
 kernel:  ? fuse_do_getattr+0x151/0x210
 kernel:  lookup_fast+0x80/0x100
 kernel:  walk_component+0x2c/0x190
 kernel:  ? inode_permission+0x74/0x1b0
 kernel:  link_path_walk.part.0.constprop.0+0x2af/0x3c0
 kernel:  ? path_init+0x298/0x3d0
 kernel:  path_lookupat+0x3e/0x1a0
 kernel:  filename_lookup+0xe4/0x200
 kernel:  user_path_at_empty+0x3e/0x70
 kernel:  do_faccessat+0x10a/0x2f0
 kernel:  __x64_sys_access+0x1c/0x30
 kernel:  x64_sys_call+0xa08/0x24b0
 kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x81/0x170
 kernel:  ? generic_permission+0x39/0x240
 kernel:  ? rseq_get_rseq_cs+0x22/0x280
 kernel:  ? mntput_no_expire+0x51/0x260
 kernel:  ? rseq_ip_fixup+0x90/0x1f0
 kernel:  ? mntput+0x24/0x50
 kernel:  ? restore_fpregs_from_fpstate+0x47/0xf0
 kernel:  ? switch_fpu_return+0x55/0xf0
 kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x89/0x260
 kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x8d/0x170
 kernel:  ? generic_permission+0x39/0x240
 kernel:  ? mntput_no_expire+0x51/0x260
 kernel:  ? rseq_get_rseq_cs+0x22/0x280
 kernel:  ? rseq_ip_fixup+0x90/0x1f0
 kernel:  ? path_put+0x1e/0x30
 kernel:  ? restore_fpregs_from_fpstate+0x47/0xf0
 kernel:  ? switch_fpu_return+0x55/0xf0
 kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x89/0x260
 kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x8d/0x170
 kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x89/0x260
 kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x8d/0x170
 kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x8d/0x170
 kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x8d/0x170
 kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x89/0x260
 kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x8d/0x170
 kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x78/0x80
 kernel: RIP: 0033:0x71851d71494b
 kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffd1283ac08 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000015
 kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000010 RCX: 000071851d71494b
 kernel: RDX: 0000000623c63317 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000623c633173c0
 kernel: RBP: 0000623c633173c0 R08: 0000623c63317200 R09: 0000623c633173c0

According to the log, it seems the problem is due to gvfsd-recent.
Can anyone help me to resolve the problem?
System specification:
   Lenovo Legion Y720
   Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

